# How do I create a public endpoint and a local endpoint that only I can access with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, publish-subscribe

So I have created my public WCF service, and it is accessible, and it works. However, I noticed upon retrieving the available methods in the wsdl that there are methods available to the public that I don't want to be accessible.

Example:

```
public interface IJobs { 
    List<Jobs> GetAllJobs(); //Good
}

public interface IJobManagement {
    void AddNewJob(Jobs job); //Bad
}
```

Config

```
<services>
  <service name="Services.Data.PublishService" >
    <clear/>
    <endpoint address="JobsHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Services.Data.IJobs" ></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="JobsTCP" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="Services.Data.IJobManagement" />
    <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" name="httpmex" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <endpoint binding="mexTcpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I thought that maybe creating a new endpoint would solve my problem but in this configuration it did nothing and I see why. I am just trying to figure out how to take IJobManagement out of the picture to the public, and make it only accessible on the local network.

This is my service class and my methods exist in there.

```
public class PublishService : IJobs, IJobsTCP { //Methods are in here. }
```

**EDIT**

And to further describe, when a new job is added I have another WCF service that will push to this WCF service and modify the `List<Jobs>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict access at the method level by implementing *principle based security*, where only users in specific groups are allow to access certain methods.

For instance, MSDN demonstrates that only **users in the role** "CalculatorClients" can access this method by annotating the method *Add* with a *PrincipalPermission*

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "CalculatorClients")]
public double Add(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

You can also restrict methods based on **client certificates**, by specifying the subject name and the certificate's thumbprint, as MSDN also demonstrates:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,
    Name = "CN=ReplaceWithSubjectName; 123456712345677E8E230FDE624F841B1CE9D41E")]
public double Multiply(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

To respond to your question about restricting by a local account, another option is to limit by account names, e.g.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="SomeAccountName")]
```

However, those local accounts should still be in a group which you could apply in the previous examples.  Limiting by an actual name is very restrictive and static to your applications development

See the [full article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Is this based on AD groups, I am assuming?

Comment: One more question for this answer, if I am running another service in the Local System account, how would I allow security on said method for that service account?

Comment: Certainly, however, for public methods you would simply not annotate the method with a security role.  This guarantees that your private methods are being called and authenticated through your network.

Comment: You are the man! I created a new security group for the type of service. Added the machine that runs the WCF service that would interact with this service, as well as added myself to do testing. Right now it is restricting me from even touching the method at all so I need to do some tweaking. Do I need anything else enable in my configuration file for this to work?